# WPF Nested Expanders not correctly adjusting parent ListBox scroll bar

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, listview, expander

I am building an automated checklist for a work process. The application compared data between two sources and generates a series of pass fail results that include the data evaluated in the test. Some tests have sub-tests that also need to be reviewed.  The input to the ViewModel is a list of test results. I selected Expanders because i can hide the data unless it needs to be reviewed. Below is my example DataTemplates for the list box, where I have a custom data template selector to select between the models

```
            <Expander >
                <Expander.Header>
                    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Image DockPanel.Dock="Left" Height="30" Width="30" Style="{DynamicResource ImageStyle}"/>
                        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="{Binding TestName}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0" Height="30" FontSize="12"/>
                        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="Override" IsEnabled="False" Height="30" Width="150"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Expander.Header>
                <Expander.Content>
                    <Grid Margin="25,5" >
                        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TestData}" Height="50" FontSize="12" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Eclispe Data" Binding="{Binding EclipseData}"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mosaiq Data" Binding="{Binding MosaiqData}"/>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </Grid>
                </Expander.Content>
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="NestedResultTemplate"  DataType="MQTransferValidation.Model.Result">
            <Expander >
                <Expander.Header>
                    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Image DockPanel.Dock="Left" Height="30" Width="30" Style="{DynamicResource ImageStyle}"/>
                        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="{Binding TestName}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0" Height="30" FontSize="12"/>
                        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="Override" IsEnabled="False" Height="30" Width="150"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Expander.Header>
                <ListBox Margin="25,5" ItemsSource="{Binding SubTestResults}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource dataTemplateSelector}">
                    
                </ListBox>
                
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
```

The issue I am having is my nested expanders are not correctly adjusting the scroll bar on the ListView that contains them. I can expand one or two levels but then every thing falls our of the listView and I can't scroll down any further.

Is there a command or option I am missing to pass the changes in Expander extent up the rendering chain?

Comment: I've created a ListView with ListViewItems containing nested Expanders similar to yours, all in pure xaml. Everything works fine, though for a smooth scrolling I needed: VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False" and VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel". If you still have issues, and you want our help, please try reproducing your issue in pure xaml, so that it's easy to reproduce.

Comment: @MaciekŚwiszczowski Thanks. Are those parameters put into the stack list view or the expanders

Comment: On the ListView

Comment: Does Scrollbar in the Expander.Content not work? Could you try to set ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled ="True" for the outer ScrollView?

Comment: @MaciekŚwiszczowski Would you mind making it an answer. I would like to set a correct response without taking credit.

Answer (score 0):

I set `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="350"` for your ListBox, then the two scrollbar can work no probelm.

The below is the updated code(just for testing) and result picture:

```
  <Grid>
    <ListView Name="myListView">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <Expander >
                    <Expander.Header>
                        <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <Image DockPanel.Dock="Left" Height="30" Width="30"/>
                            <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="{Binding TestName}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0" Height="30" FontSize="12"/>
                            <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="Override" IsEnabled="False" Height="30" Width="150"/>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </Expander.Header>
                    <ListBox Margin="25,5" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="350">
                        <ListBoxItem Content="Start"></ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding EclipseData}"></ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding EclipseData}"></ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding EclipseData}"></ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding EclipseData}"></ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding EclipseData}"></ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding EclipseData}"></ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding EclipseData}"></ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding EclipseData}"></ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding EclipseData}"></ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding MosaiqData}"></ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding MosaiqData}"></ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding MosaiqData}"></ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding MosaiqData}"></ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding MosaiqData}"></ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding MosaiqData}"></ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding MosaiqData}"></ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding MosaiqData}"></ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding MosaiqData}"></ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding MosaiqData}"></ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding MosaiqData}"></ListBoxItem>
                        <ListBoxItem Content="End"></ListBoxItem>
                    </ListBox>
                </Expander>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
       
    </ListView>
   
</Grid>
```

[image]